# Question migrated, but user doesn't exist on the new site

Tags: discussion, migration

I stumbled upon a question which was migrated from Security to Stack Overflow. The problem is that the user doesn't have an account on Stack Overflow and the question needs clarifications from the OP before it can be answered.

What happens in this case? Is the user notified to create a profile on the new site? Does he see the new question link? Does he receives notifications when a comment is posted on his question on the new site?

This situation **is bad** from several points: first it's a waste of time if the user cannot answer the comments. Second it doesn't add any value to the site for the same reason. And even if there is an answer to the question the user cannot accept it and the post cannot be closed as solved.

We could just close the question, but then we don't give a chance to the user to answer clarifications.

Should we do something about this or is it that this is so rare that we shouldn't bother with this?

Comment: *I don't want to give a link to the question because I don't want to single out this case.* Linking the post adds nothing to your question, so just leave it out. And we don't single out questions. Bad questions need to be closed either way, and usually happens with or without Meta, so not too much worry about that.